# Ms Graph v5.0 How to get all SharePoint list items

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I wrote piece of code and it works, but this way I can only get 200 elements of the list, the question is how to get everything?

this is what I wrote

```
var  response = await graphClient
         .Sites[siteId]
         .Lists[listId]
         .Items.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                    {
                        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[]
                        {
                            "fields($select=_x0421__x0434__x0440_,_x0421__x0435__x043a__x0446__x04," +
                            "_x041f__x043e__x0432__x0435__x04,_x041a__x043e__x0440__x043f__x04,_x0417__x0430__x0445__x0432__x04,_x0420__x043e__x0437__x0446__x04," +
                            "Title,_x041e__x0434__x002e__x0432__x04,_x041a__x0456__x043b__x044c__x04," +
                            "_x041a__x0456__x043b__x044c__x040,_x041f__x0456__x0434__x0440__x04," +
                            "_x041f__x0440__x0438__x043c__x04)"
                        };
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [PageIterator](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#pageiterator) to get all items. `PageIterator` handles the `odata.nextLink` until the last page is reached.

```
var  response = await graphClient
         .Sites[siteId]
         .Lists[listId]
         .Items.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                    {
                        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[]
                        {
                            "fields($select=_x0421__x0434__x0440_,_x0421__x0435__x043a__x0446__x04," +
                            "_x041f__x043e__x0432__x0435__x04,_x041a__x043e__x0440__x043f__x04,_x0417__x0430__x0445__x0432__x04,_x0420__x043e__x0437__x0446__x04," +
                            "Title,_x041e__x0434__x002e__x0432__x04,_x041a__x0456__x043b__x044c__x04," +
                            "_x041a__x0456__x043b__x044c__x040,_x041f__x0456__x0434__x0440__x04," +
                            "_x041f__x0440__x0438__x043c__x04)"
                        };
                    });

// list which contains all items
var listItems = new List<ListItem>();
var pageIterator = PageIterator<ListItem, ListItemCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(graphServiceClient, response,item=>
{
    listItems.Add(item);
    return true;
});

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```